# Need help with eCommerce solutions

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal, e-commerce

I'm trying to make a site where the user can choose between three options and then quickly pay (on the site, not redirected to paypal) and then once they pay are able to view the product (video). I want everything to be on one page. I have been looking at Ubercart for Drupal and WP eCommerce for Wordpress. They both seem overly complex for what I need, however, I can only program in HTML/CSS and I'm just starting to use PHP. Does anyone know of a guide, easier way, or CMS with an easier to use module for eCommerce that would fit my solution.

Comment: How do you want your users to pay, using what methods?

Comment: I was looking at that paypal site and they have the 2 click digital download or the paypal pro flow or whatever. Basically, it will be with PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a number of sites with WP-Ecommerce... Avoid using it if you can. It is buggy and inflexible. There are a number of other ecommerce plugins in WordPress plugin repository.

Answer (score 0):

Get an account with Paypal and it will let you generate "Buy it Now" buttons for your products that are static HTML and manage all the payment process via Paypal. There's no signup fee. Their rates are a bit on the high side (starting at 2.9% + $0.30), but for low volume or testing new ideas they're a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Give [BigCommerce](http://above.bigcommerce.com) a try.

It is easiest to setup and use by far and if you have basic knowledge in HTML/CSS you'll be able to edit the templates no worries.

Integrates with a tonne of payment gateways out of the box.

Comes with free 15 day trial too.